# regex: find string ending with * or?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a regex that matches words ending with either `*` or(exclusively- not both at once) `+` and another for the string starting with ?

Here's what I tried:

```
import re


txt = "~The ?rain in+ spain*"
special = f"\\*+"
special2 = f"\\~"
x = re.search(f"\w*{special}\b", txt) #to find in+ and spain*
x2 = re.search(f"^{special2}\w", txt) #to find ~The

print(x.string, x.group(), x.span() )
print(x2.string, x2.group(), x2.span() )
```

Comment: Those regexes look for the literal text `{special}` and `{special2}`, because you didn't use f-strings.

Comment: @JohnGordon, replaced r with f and tried it, didn't work... I edited the post. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: The r-strings where it is important were not replaced by f-strings in the shown code.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, sorry I edited 2 lines only instead of 4, but in the code I  tried I have f-strings for the 4 lines

Comment: Cut and paste your actual code, not retyped code with errors

Comment: @MarkTolonen This is already the version pasted from my editor! (actually, copied it to my editor to be more precise, but still, It's the exact thing I have in my editor)

Comment: @aNormalPerson After multiple edits...just making sure 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/KjCDxn/2)

```
import re

re.findall("~\w+|\w+(?:\+|\*)", text)
```

---

```
['~The', 'in+', 'spain*']
```

Comment: You could shorten it to `~\w+|\w+[+*]`